# element hq/web creating docker image

Tags: javascript, element, docker-image

```
52.4 <s> [webpack.Progress] 92% sealing asset processing copy-webpack-plugin
252.7 <s> [webpack.Progress] 92% sealing asset processing PersistentChildCompilerSingletonPlugin
252.7 <s> [webpack.Progress] 92% sealing asset processing TerserPlugin
345.4 Killed
346.1 error Command failed with exit code 137.
346.1 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
347.3 error Command failed with exit code 137.
347.3 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
------
Dockerfile:20
--------------------
  18 |    
  19 |
  20 | >>> RUN dos2unix /src/scripts/docker-package.sh && bash /src/scripts/docker-package.sh
  21 |
  22 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c dos2unix /src/scripts/docker-package.sh && bash /src/scripts/docker-package.sh" did not complete successfully: exit code: 137

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/default/default/jcopj833yfwimz3eu6wew2917
```

creating a docker image but giving this error